# ElasticSearch: (OR) wildcard on two fields AND match exactly one

Tags: elasticsearch

I am *very* new to the Elastic world and I am having a lot of troubles understand the logic behind some operations.
Currently studying and trying a lot of stuff, so I am a bit confused right now and I need some hints.

The scenario.
I have the following (`client` type) documents in the `clients` index (don't worry: the names are football players and the phone numbers are not real):

```
    {
      "firstName" : "Alessandro",
      "lastName" : "Nesta",
      "phoneNumber" : "+3949304903",
      "merchantId" : "90339203812831293"
    },
    {
      "firstName" : "Alessandro",
      "lastName" : "Del Piero",
      "phoneNumber" : "+39129302902",
      "merchantId" : "90339203812831293"
    },
    {
      "firstName" : "Alessandro",
      "lastName" : "Costacurta",
      "phoneNumber" : "+39098921321",
      "merchantId" : "1239021392839238"
    }
```

Now, the search query I am looking for basically does this: given a `merchantId` and a query string, try to find the query string inside firstName or inside lastName, but be sure that merchantId is exactly like the one passed in the query.

Let's say I have a query string "Aless" and a merchantId "90339203812831293 ", in the SQL world I was going to do:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
  `clients`
WHERE
  `merchantId` = "90339203812831293"
AND 
(
  `firstName` LIKE "Aless%" OR `lastName` LIKE "Aless%"
);
```

And the results should be:

```
{
  "firstName" : "Alessandro",
  "lastName" : "Nesta",
  "phoneNumber" : "+3949304903",
  "merchantId" : "90339203812831293"
},
{
  "firstName" : "Alessandro",
  "lastName" : "Del Piero",
  "phoneNumber" : "+39129302902",
  "merchantId" : "90339203812831293"
}
```

What I have tried? Basically different from combinations, from putting the merchantId in the filter section, to multi_match.

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "wildcard": {
          "firstName": "aless*"
        }
      },
      {
        "wildcard": {
          "lastName": "aless*"
        }
      }
    ],
    "must": {
      "match": {
        "merchantId": "90339203812831293"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

0 results (If I remove the merchantId part works fine).

I have tried with query strings, too:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "Del*",
        "fields": [
          "firstName",
          "lastName"
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "term": {
        "merchantId": "90339203812831293"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Same problem.
Can you please me point to what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's incredible, 1 day of full frustration trying and as soon as I have asked here I finally found a solution:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Aless*",
            "fields": [
              "firstName",
              "lastName"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "merchant_id": "90339203812831293"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However I am more than open to new solutions because I am pretty sure this is not the best one.
I can still modify even the structure of the document, if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the multi match way?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Aless",
            "fields": ["firstName", "lastName"]
         }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "merchant_id": "90339203812831293"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": 
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "Aless",
                "fields": ["firstname", "lastname"]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "merchant_id": "90339203812831293"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For what I have read until now, I think that a solution with multi_match + filter would be the best in my case? Anyway, thanks Anita but I get 0 hits with both!